# What is the difference between React.Component and Component?

Tags: reactjs

There are stateful components which made by class ClassName extends React.Component and stateless component which can be made by a function componentName(prop). However, I saw some react tutorials that create component by class className extends Component. What is this?

Comment: You can write `import React from 'react'; class ClassName extends React.Component` or `import React, { Component } from 'react'; class ClassName extends Component`. It's the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the same, the diference is when you import.

If you are not specific with import:

```
import React from 'react'
```

You must be more specific when extends,

`...extends React.Component`,

If you be more specific when import:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

You can extend with Component word alone.